# I was asked how addition, subtractions, & multiplication of polynomial impact on the resulting degree of polynomial using algebraic example to demos.

Tags: calculus, functions

I know what a polynomial is and how its highest degree is determined but I don't how addition, multiplication, and subtraction impact its degree.

Please help me answer this question of mine.

Comment: We always have $\deg(f\pm g) \leq \max (\deg f, \deg g), \deg (f \cdot g) \leq \deg f \cdot \deg g$. However, if the leading coefficients are equal or some coefficients are equal, the degree can be lower. It depends, where exactly you need that.

Comment: Hints:  $(a+bx+cx^2)+(A+Bx+Cx^2)=(a+A)+(b+B)x+(c+C)x^2$.  Could an $x^3$ term have appeared out of thin air?  $(1+x-x^2) + (1-x+x^2)=2+0x+0x^2=2$.  What is the degree of this?  Is it the same as $(1+x-x^2)$ was?

Comment: Why don't you try adding, subtracting, and multiplying some polynomials, Rita, and see for yourself what effect the operations have on the degree?